# Html.BeginForm strange behaviour

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a feature in my ASP.NET MVC 5 app that sends a link to the user account email to reset the user account password.

The URL sent is something like this : `https://mysite/User/b620e7b6-06fa-4c77-b831-88a74d899c16`, so when the user clicks it makes a `GET` requisition to this action

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ChangePasswordValidationFilter]
    [Route("User/{code:guid}")]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(Guid code)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In the **ChangePassword** View i have a `@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "User", FormMethod.Post))` that should point to this action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(PasswordDTO model)
    {}
```

But when i click on the URL, i tap F12 and in the HTML form the code is: `<form action="/User/b620e7b6-06fa-4c77-b831-88a74d899c16" method="POST"`.

Why its like this? Because of the route? And how to fix it?

Comment: First, view source, not just inspect the code with your browser's developer tools. The dev tools show the HTML code as it is in the DOM, not how it was sent from the server. Second, we need to see all your view code here to see exactly what you're doing. Also, include any custom JavaScript you've written that may be running on the page.

Comment: Why is `/User/b620e7b6-06fa-4c77-b831-88a74d899c16` the route for `ChangePassword`? Shouldn't it be `/User/ChangePassword/b620e7b6-06fa-4c77-b831-88a74d899c16` (or similar)?